# With dbt how do I use a model cte in a macro call in a jinja expression?

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

How would I reference a previously defined cte inside of a macro call, inside of a jinja expression block?

```
with stg_example_table as (

  select *
  from {{ ref('stg_db__example_table') }}
  where {{ ref('stg_db__example_table') }}.example_column = 'foobar'

),

earliest_date as (
                                                   THIS
  {{                                         vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    get_earliest_date('month', 'created_at', stg_example_table)
  }}                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  
)

select * from earliest_date
```

I can't seem to reference the cte, stg_example_table, in that location in a way that works. How should it be referenced in a way that will work?

The macro get_earliest_date(), works if I use `ref('stg_db__example_table')`. But then I'm getting the wrong value since the table isn't reduced as it would be from the cte.

I could create another stg model that has the filters I need and ref() that one, but it'd be nice to just use the cte here.

I have also tried various forms of:

```
{% set earliest_date = run_query("select min(created_at)::date from stg_db__example_table").columns[0][0] %}
```

And then referencing the set earliest_date, but I could not get that to work.

For reference, this is the get_earliest_date() macro:

```
{% macro get_earliest_date(date_component, column_name, relation) %}

{% set query %}
  select
    date_trunc({{ date_component }}, min({{ column_name }}))::date as earliest
  from {{ relation }}
{% endset %}

{% set results = run_query(query) %}


{% if execute %}

{% set result = results.columns[0][0] %}

{% else %}
{% set result = null %}

{% endif %}

{{ return(result) }}

{% endmacro %}
```

The example code is simplified, but eventually I want to get a date_spine() with:

```
  {{ 
    dbt_utils.date_spine(
      datepart = "month",
      start_date = get_earliest_date('month', 'created_at', stg_example_table),
      end_date = "date_trunc('month', current_date())"
    )
  }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbt doesn't parse your model, so it simply doesn't know what `stg_example_table` is.

If you're looking to re-use a CTE, it should probably be its own model (a macro would be another choice). You can use the `ephemeral` materialization and dbt won't persist anything to your warehouse -- it just interpolates the model as a CTE. There are some limitations for how you can `ref` an ephemeral model, but I think in this case, since you're calling `get_earliest_date` from a model, it should work fine.

```sql
-- in stg_example_table.sql
{{ config(materialized="ephemeral") }}
select *
from {{ ref('stg_db__example_table') }}
where {{ ref('stg_db__example_table') }}.example_column = 'foobar'

-- in your_model.sql
...
{{ 
    dbt_utils.date_spine(
      datepart = "month",
      start_date = get_earliest_date('month', 'created_at', ref('stg_example_table')),
      end_date = "date_trunc('month', current_date())"
    )
}}
```